# Query results stored into one variable

Tags: php, mysql

I've read through some other posts that were similar but I can't seem to get a good implementation of them. I'm calling a php script from another program that needs the results returned in one variable, space or comma separated. The php connects to a db (no problem there) and runs a query that will return 2 to 6 or so matching rows. I need those results together in one variable but can't seem to get it.

Here's where I'm stuck.

```
$t = "SELECT user FROM call_times WHERE client='$clientid' AND start <= $date AND end >=          $date";
$result = mysql_query($t) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$temp = $row['user'];
}
echo $temp;
```

The query runs fine, but you can see from the code what I'm trying (and failing) to do in the lower part. I need $temp to hold a list of results (ex: 5567889 57479992 4335780 (each of which is a different entry in user column)).

Thanks so much!

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Also, have you tried [`group_concat()`](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $array[] = $row['user'];
}

$string = implode(" ", $array);
```

Now $string has the space-separated values of the `user` column.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try [`group_concat()`](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/) and you won't need PHP to manipulate the results.